# Run a Windows application without displaying its GUI

Tags: windows-7, powershell, shell-script, vbscript

Is there a way to run a Windows application without displaying its GUI window?

I have a 3rd party Windows application which does not have any command line parameter or switch to suppress its GUI. I need to start it in the background, and interact only programmatically with it, using data exchange APIs published by that 3rd party app.

I tried creating a Task in Task Scheduler with the Hidden check box, but even then when I start the task manually, the app's window is getting displayed. I guess the app is programmed to bring itself to focus after startup.

I need this solution for Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the name of the 3rd party app?

Comment: Its a locally available Business ERP product. The name should be irrelevant here.

Comment: Did you find a workable solution to this? I have two that should work just fine but if you have a working solution per the two below answers, then my answer(s) wouldn't be too useful to you. One Windows native and another using Open Source app solution.

Comment: Anyway, you can share :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use the Win32 API via PowerShell to find and hide the window(s) for the target application.

Example code:

```
$definition = @"    
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
      static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

      public static void Show(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
      }

      public static void Hide(string wClass, string wName)
      {
         IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(wClass, wName);
         if ((int)hwnd > 0)
            ShowWindow(hwnd, 0);
      }
"@

add-type -MemberDefinition $definition -Namespace my -Name WinApi

[my.WinApi]::Hide('Notepad', 'Untitled - Notepad')
```

Source code from [Aryadev's answer to "Hide a Window with Powershell ISE?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15525320/225906) over on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have collected some Information and references in a [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36903582/4068240). Also if its related to C# it Covers. Net and win32 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your application via VBScript, the example uses wmplayer.exe (save the below line as .vbs file):

```vb
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe""", 0
```